# Android Lollipop 5.0.1 apps cache saved in apps data Example:

Tags: applications, 5.0-lollipop, stock-android

In Android Lollipop 5.0.1: cache are stored within apps data. Example:
Facebook app had saved 400mb, not as a deletable cache but as app data. When I want to free up space I have to clear data and log in again and again... How to solve this issue?

Comment: The most sensible solution - not to use FB, and the apps like FB:) Such crap is not worth of having it on the device.

Comment: The problem is that not only fb but all apps have the same issue